# Magento order email missing style

Tags: email, magento

I have a question regarding the magento order emails.

I have created my own order template by loading the default template and modifying it. When i take a look via the 'preview template' button on there, the email appears without order information (of course) but with every styling etc.

However when my customer gets the email it is pure text with no styling at all.

What could i have been doing wrong

Idk if it helps but here is my email template:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style='background: #fff' class="email-heading">
                        <h1 style='color: #68883e;'>Thank you for your order</h1>
                        <p>Your order is being process right now</p>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="order-details">
            <h3 style='display: inline; float: left'>Your order <span class="no-link">#{{var order.increment_id}}</span></h3>
            <p style='display: inline; float: right'>Placed on {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="order-information">
        <td>
            {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/if}}
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Bill to:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>

                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Client:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getclientfirstname().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Shipping method:</h6>
                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Payment method:</h6>
                        {{var payment_html}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- asd-->
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm facing the same problem after upgrade to 2.4.6.
I only had _email-extend.less in my theme and it was working before,
now i can see the preview styled but not the email

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the CSS classes to stylize the templates. 
Also, you shouldn't use the file with the styles info, that is located anywhere else, as they are not supported by the majority of the email services.

Instead, you can directly use the attribute tags (to implement the stylazation) or use the styles right in the email code (using the tag `<style>`)

And here is the list of tags you can use:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/